# Place div at center and update function when user try to re-size window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var wH = $(window).height();
var wW = $(window).width();
var sT = $(window).scrollTop();
var sL = $(window).scrollLeft();

jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, ((wH - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + sT) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, ((wW - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + sL) + "px");
    return this;
}

$('div').center();
```

I try to place div at center of page and I have found a function can do this.

However, when windows re-size or user try to zoom in out, this function didn't update new position.

Is anyway to run this function when user try to re-size windows or zoom in out?

Comment: Bind a handler to the window resize event and call it from there. Learn about event handling here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the jQuery resize method should do exactly what you want:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('div').center();
});
```

Alternatively, you can do this with a plain DOM method:

```
window.onresize = function () { $('div').center(); };
```

However, the plain DOM method will remove any existing handlers bound to the window resize event and may not behave identically between browsers.

Also, you'll need to move these lines into your function so that they update when the handler gets called:

```
var wH = $(window).height();
var wW = $(window).width();
var sT = $(window).scrollTop();
var sL = $(window).scrollLeft();
```

Comment: Actually, I think I may have found the problem